# Using sox to trim a sound file within Django form class

Tags: python, django, audio, sox, wavesurfer.js

I'm trying to build an application which allows users to edit their uploaded sound files. So far the user is able to retrieve their sounds and display as waveform with the wavesurfer js library. The idea is to grab the start and end points on the wavesurfer region selected, and pass those values to the form class (where sox will trim the file) using an updateview. I pip installed [pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox) and installed sox in my virtual env. This is what I have so far with my urls.py:

```
url(r'^update_sound/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', UpdateSound.as_view(), name='update_sound'),
```

my forms.py:

```
import sox
class UpdateSound(forms.ModelForm):
def trim_sound(self):
    file = self.cleaned_data.get('sound', False)
    tfm = sox.Transformer(file)
    tfm.trim(0,0.3)



class Meta:
    model = Sounds
    fields = [
    'sound',
    ]
```

And the update view

```
class UpdateSound(UpdateView):      
    model = Sounds
    form_class = UpdateSound    
    template_name= 'sound_detail.html'
```

My main question is, 1.Is this a good way of going about editing sound files and 2. What should I add to my form class to make this work? I've looked at the sox docs and still not entirely clear on what to do. Should I be passing the sound file as an argument to the transformer? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The pysox module does not use [libsox](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libsox) but creates a subprocess for each audio file to process (source code [here](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox/blob/master/sox/core.py#L48)). It certainly works, but if your server handles more than, say, 100 QPS, then you should take the overhead of creating and destroying processes into consideration.
2. As the doc goes, you should write

   tfm.build('path/to/input_audio', 'path/to/output_audio')

   after applying effects (tfm.trim in your case).

   Keep in mind that you should install sox (apt/yum install sox) on your server, and it does not support writting to MP3/M4A/OGG etc., so you'll probably need an additional call to lame/ffmpeg to encode the output for downloading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It really helped me understand how sox works. One question I have about the paths, do you know within the context of the django form, how to specify the paths? The input path specifically, can I just plug in the 'file' variable which grabs the 'sound' field?

Comment: You probably have to write sound data into a local file. SoX supports reading audio from standard input, but, unluckily, pysox does not. Neither could it fetch from a remote URL, which might be your case.